# Flag someone if he purchased same product before and if he purchased any product

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Situation:**

I need to add two column flags identified as such:

- Whether or not the person puchased the **same** product before the purchase date.
- Whether or not the person purchased **any other** product before the purchase date.

The output should have 5 columns:

1. Email
2. ProductName
3. DatePurchased
4. SameProduct (0 = No, 1 = Yes)
5. AnyProduct (0 = No, 1 = Yes)

Raw data looks like this:

```
abc@gmail.com   cucumber    01-02-2019
abc@gmail.com   orange      04-02-2019
abc@gmail.com   grapefruit  15-02-2019
cde@gmail.com   blackberry  06-02-2019
cde@gmail.com   lime        15-02-2019
cde@gmail.com   lime        20-02-2019
zzz@gmail.com   apple       02-02-2019
zzz@gmail.com   apple       18-02-2019
zzz@gmail.com   orange      19-02-2019
zzz@gmail.com   apple       28-02-2019
```

**Objective:**

And my ouput would look like this:

```
Email           ProductName DatePurchased   SameProduct     AnyProduct
abc@gmail.com   cucumber    01-02-2019      0               0
abc@gmail.com   orange      04-02-2019      0               1
abc@gmail.com   grapefruit  15-02-2019      0               1
cde@gmail.com   blackberry  06-02-2019      0               0
cde@gmail.com   lime        15-02-2019      0               1
cde@gmail.com   lime        20-02-2019      1               1
zzz@gmail.com   apple       02-02-2019      0               0   
zzz@gmail.com   apple       18-02-2019      1               1   
zzz@gmail.com   orange      19-02-2019      0               1
zzz@gmail.com   apple       28-02-2019      1               1
```

What I tried: 
I tried to join on itself twice and use case statements but I feel this way is extremely inefficient.

**Dummy data:**

```
create table #table1 (email varchar(20), productname varchar(20), datepurchased date)
insert into #table1 values
('abc@gmail.com','cucumber','2019-02-01'),
('abc@gmail.com','orange','2019-02-04'),
('abc@gmail.com','grapefruit','2019-02-15'),
('cde@gmail.com','blackberry','2019-02-06'),
('cde@gmail.com','lime','2019-02-15'),
('cde@gmail.com','lime','2019-02-20'),
('zzz@gmail.com','apple','2019-02-02'),
('zzz@gmail.com','apple','2019-02-18'),
('zzz@gmail.com','orange','2019-02-19'),
('zzz@gmail.com','apple','2019-02-28')
```

**Note:** My actual data has over 100M rows. Im not sure what type of query would make the processing of data as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more option to get the result.

I use ROW_NUMBER()-1 so we can give the first occurrence a zero value. Then I use SIGN() to convert any positive value into 1.

```
SELECT *,
    SameProduct = SIGN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email, productname ORDER BY datepurchased)-1),
    AnyProduct  = SIGN(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY datepurchased)-1)
FROM #table1
ORDER BY email, datepurchased;
```

If needed, it could be casted into bit to get the same result as using SIGN(), but just in this case where all values are positive.

```
SELECT *,
    SameProduct = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email, productname ORDER BY datepurchased)-1 AS bit),
    AnyProduct  = CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY email ORDER BY datepurchased)-1 AS bit)
FROM #table1
ORDER BY email, datepurchased;
```

Comment: may you please show what you mean by casting into ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to give an example on how to use CAST instead of SIGN.

Comment: But what does it do ? whats the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be using `LAG()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`.

`LAG()` always refers to the previous record, therefore quite useful to check if the previous and current products are equal.

`ROW_NUMBER()` would be used just to mark the first buy (row number = 1)

Of course the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses are important, to get the records in the right order.

I also checked the solution of Vamsi Prabhalas, but the performance with `IIF` seems to be way faster than `CASE-WHEN`.

```
SELECT email
      ,productname
      ,datepurchased
      ,IIF(LAG(productname) OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email, datepurchased) = productname, 1,0) AS SameProduct
      ,IIF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY email, datepurchased) = 1, 0, 1) AS AnyProduct
  FROM #table1
```

Comment: You don't need to order by email if you're partitioning by email. The email on each partition will always be the same.

Comment: @LuisCazares you are right. just a habit of me. should be no difference regarding execution plans

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with `count` window function or `row_number`.

```
--count
select t.*
       ,case when count(*) over(partition by email,productname order by datepurchased) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as same_prev
       ,case when count(*) over(partition by email order by datepurchased) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as any_prev
from tbl t

--row_number
select t.*
           ,case when row_number() over(partition by email,productname order by datepurchased) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as same_prev
           ,case when row_number() over(partition by email order by datepurchased) > 1 then 1 else 0 end as any_prev
from tbl t
```

Comment: wouldnt this window function be extremely slow for millions of rows? there's only an index on the email column

Comment: you can experiment with creating new index to include `datepurchased` column as well and compare the different execution plans.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by email, productname order by datepurchased) 
             then 0 else 1
        end) as same_product,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by email order by datepurchased) 
             then 0 else 1
        end) as any_product
from #table1 t;
```

Note that the only difference is the `row_number()`.

You can also do this without a `case` comparison:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(max(1) over (partition by email, productname order by datepurchased rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as same_product,
       coalesce(max(1) over (partition by email order by datepurchased rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0) as any_product
from table1 t
order by email, datepurchased;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9d150a18247386eb48006d0e04f8db07) is a db<>fiddle.